# Issue in case statement in pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I am using below code to get one data frame but getting error. If will remove case statement from code then it will work fine.

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
ivr_icm_cfs_lookup = spark.table("sample_table").where(F.col("tier") == "Servicing").select("fig","fig_bu","tier") .withColumn("fig",F.regexp_replace(F.col("fig"),"[^0-9a-zA-Z]",' ')).withColumn("fig_bu",F.when((F.col("fig_bu") == 'OPEN' & F.col("tier") == 'Academy', F.upper("tier")).otherwise(F.col("fig_bu"))))
```

Comment: Error:
File "/opt/mapr/spark/spark-2.3.2/python/pyspark/sql/column.py", line 116, in _
njc = getattr(self._jc, name)(jc)
File "/opt/mapr/spark/spark-2.3.2/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1257, in __call__
File "/opt/mapr/spark/spark-2.3.2/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 63, in deco
return f(*a, **kw) py4j.protocol.Py4JError: An error occurred while calling o113.and. Trace:
py4j.Py4JException: Method and([class java.lang.String]) does not exist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was problem with your brackets sir. Try now

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
ivr_icm_cfs_lookup = spark.table("sample_table").where(F.col("tier") == "Servicing").select("fig","fig_bu","tier") .withColumn("fig",F.regexp_replace(F.col("fig"),"[^0-9a-zA-Z]",' ')).withColumn("fig_bu",F.when((F.col("fig_bu") == 'OPEN') & (F.col("tier") == 'Academy'), F.upper("tier")).otherwise(F.col("fig_bu")))
```

If this is really not working for you, then you can try spark sql by registering the dataframe as table then writing your case when in sql.

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
ivr_icm_cfs_lookup = spark.table("sample_table").where(F.col("tier") == "Servicing").select("fig","fig_bu","tier") .withColumn("fig",F.regexp_replace(F.col("fig"),"[^0-9a-zA-Z]",' '))

ivr_icm_cfs_lookup.createOrReplaceTempView('ivr_icm_cfs_lookup_table')
ivr_icm_cfs_lookup_df = spark.sql('''
select *, case when fig_bu='OPEN' and tier='Academy' then upper(tier) else fig_bu END as fig_bu_2 from ivr_icm_cfs_lookup_table
'''
```

This way you can add the required column.

Comment: still getting error:
  File "/opt/mapr/spark/spark-2.3.2/python/pyspark/sql/functions.py", line 42, in _
    jc = getattr(sc._jvm.functions, name)(col._jc if isinstance(col, Column) else col)
  File "/opt/mapr/spark/spark-2.3.2/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1257, in __call__
  File "/opt/mapr/spark/spark-2.3.2/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 63, in deco
    return f(*a, **kw)
 "/opt/mapr/spark/spark-2.3.2/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py"
py4j.protocol.Py4JError: An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.sql.functions.upper. Trace:

Comment: Is anyone can help me on the above issue?

Comment: Kindly help me on this?

Comment: What is the exact error, it is working fine in my system?

Comment: attached the error above. kindly suggest some other way.